# menu problems using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, menubar

I have a table with two columns called rugby_union and matchleague.
i have created 2 queries to display distinct rugby_union and matchleague. when i have dropdown on menu it must display matchleague from rugby_union only.
herewith code I am using:

```
$sql="select distinct(union_league) from teams where league_complete ='No' ";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 
$matchleaguecomp[] = $row; 
}

$sql1="select distinct(rugby_union) AS rugby_union from teams where league_complete ='No' ";
$query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){ 
$union_list[] = $row1; 
}
```

PHP code in navbar:

```
<?php                       
    for($i=0;$i<count ($union_list);$i++){  
?>
<li>
    <a href="#"><?php echo $union_list[$i][0]; ?></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" 
         style="position: absolute; left: 160px; top: 0px; display: none;
                height: <?php if(count($matchleaguecomp)>0) {
                                  echo '260px;'; 
                              } else { 
                                  echo (count($matchleaguecomp)*26).'px'; 
                              } ?>  
                overflow: auto;">
        <?php
            for($i=0;$i<count($matchleaguecomp);$i++){                      
                //$fixture_name=$url->encode("name=".$matchleaguecomp[$i][0]);
            $fixture_name="name=".$matchleaguecomp[$i][0];
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $include_path.'new_logs.php?'.$fixture_name; ?>">
                <?php echo $matchleaguecomp[$i][0]; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php  } ?>
    </ul>
</li>
<?php  } ?>
```

thanks in advance, I cannot figure out why it does not display the unions list with the league

Comment: you never output anything from `$union_list`, and you're building that array wrong - you're dumping everything into array key `[0]`, which means you overwrite each previous record with the next fetched one.

Comment: Hi Marc B would you please edit code to display information correctly

Comment: `while(...) { $union_list[] = $row1 }`

Comment: I did fix it but cannot display the list of unions

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Answer (score 0):

First, pay attention to what @tadman said about mysql_query being obsolete...
Here is your fixed code:

```
$sql="select distinct(union_league) as `union_league` from teams where league_complete ='No' ";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 
$matchleaguecomp[] = $row['union_league']; // you need to get the returned value from the array
}

$sql1="select distinct(rugby_union) AS rugby_union from teams where league_complete ='No' ";
$query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){ 
$union_list[] = $row1['rugby_union']; // you need to get the returned value from the array
}
```

Comment: Len, thanks union_league works but rugby_unions still have the same result only show 1 union

Comment: How many do you get when you run that query from the command line or in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Len, when I run in PHPMyadmin I get 2 when i run print_r it display everything

Comment: Just for fun, change AS rugby_union to AS `rugby_union`. It shouldn't make a difference but at least the structure of the query will match the structure of the one that is giving you success. I have seen stranger things...

Comment: The sql query is 100% correct, it is the PHP script that cause problem. for union_league it works 100%

Comment: Set up both tables on sqlfiddle and add some sample data. I'll pull it down from there and run some tests locally